# Specify a file as a source for Twitter Bootstrap type ahead functionality

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement the Bootstrap typeahead functionality in my webpage.The JS code is as follows:

```
<script>
var subjects = ['PHP', 'MySQL', 'SQL', 'PostgreSQL', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'HTML5', 'CSS3', 'JSON'];
$('#search').typeahead({source: subjects})
     </script>
```

The HTML code for the input box is as follows:

```
<input name="IPinput" id="search" type="text" autocomplete="off"  class="span3" placeholder="Type for auto suggest" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" />
```

This works perfectly fine.However,my actual data source has close to 2000 odd entries and I really do not want to clutter up my HTML page with all this data.Can I reference a file on the HTML page within the javascript which can have these enteries ?

Comment: what type of file is it? .txt? .js?

Comment: i really don't know..can it be a text file ? it would be awesome if I could just reference a text file with the entries in it..The bootstrap document says that the data source must be an array..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Bootstrap allows you to define a function to get the source data from, in there you can use AJAX to load your text file like this:

```
$('#search').typeahead({
    source: function(query, process){
        return $.get('path/to/source.txt', function (data) {
            return process(data.split(','));
        });
    }
});
```

The above example will create an array from a list of comma separated keywords

Comment: Koala_dev..i tried this..but it does not work..The auto suggest no longer works...can you tell me what format should the contents of 'path/to/source.txt' be in ?

Comment: @Amistad I suggest you define the format that works best for you and then adjust the code, in the example above the terms are separated by comma: `PHP,MySQL,SQL,PostgreSQL,HTML`, make sure the path you specify for the file is correct and check your browser's console for any erros